# Linq into the array then find values in the array and list to combobox

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I would like to return the result of the `LINQ` query to the array, the list then look in this array for example with the letter `"A"`. And return the list to the combobox containing all the letters `"A"`.

My linq query:

```
var collectionName = (
    from row in repos.GetTable<Table_Names>() 
    select row.Name
    ).Distinct().ToArray();
```

And I do not know now how to search the array so that it will find all of them containing the letter `"A"`.

Ultimately, I would like to search in the array instead of sending queries to the database. That would make the list in the combobox narrow down dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to get the filtered collection, instead for perform search after getting the collection. So I suggest you to use a [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) clause like the following to get filtered items only:

```
string searchString ="A";

from row in repos.GetTable<Table_Names>() 
where row.Name.Contains(searchString)
select row.Name;
```

Instead for `Contains` you can also try [`StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to get the collection of strings that starts with the given search text.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to filter in the database, you can use `linq to objects` to further filter the collection in memory:

```
var filtered = collectionName.Where(item => item.Contains("A")).ToArray();
```

Comment: here, you dropped this: `)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlMethods.Like in LINQ query. Check the code below

```
private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = getItems(comboBox1.Text);
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
    }
    public static List<ComboboxItem> getItems(string text)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        try
        {
            List<ComboboxItem> Ilist = new List<ComboboxItem>();
            var query =  from x in context.testComboBoxes where SqlMethods.Like(x.name, '%' + text +'%') select x;
            foreach (var q in query)
            {
                ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
                item.ID = q.id;
                item.Name = q.name;
                Ilist.Add(item);
            }
            return Ilist;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public class ComboboxItem
    {
        public object ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```